# Есть ли слово "задействуя"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Задействовав — это уже сделав. А если ты занимаешься чем то, в процессе "задействуя" какие-то ресурсы, то какое слово употребляется? Есть ли такая форма?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Задействовав или задействуя?** Суффикс В является основным, но в Нацкорпусе  можно найти 13 примеров с суффиксом В и 7 примеров с суффиксом Я.

**Пояснение** (неосновной суффикс А/Я как замена суффикса В)

Для образования деепричастий **совершенного вида** может использоваться основа простого будущего времени и **суффикс А/Я**: прочтут – прочтя, найдут – найдя. В одних случаях эти деепричастия образуют **вариантные формы:** заметив – заметя. В  других случаях они являются **более употребительными**, чем формы с суффиксами В/ВШИ/ШИ: принеся, выйдя, зайдя, обретя, уведя. Такие деепричастия часто используются **в устойчивых выражениях**: сломя голову, спустя  рукава.

**Примеры**

1) Между тем члены преступной группы пытаются добиться развала уголовного дела, **задействуя** "серьезные административные и финансовые ресурсы. Чака продолжает вылизывать щенка, играть с ним, удивительным животным чутьём **задействуя** в игры именно пораженную группу мышц. Собственно в сферах компетенции ЮНЕСКО ― науке, образовании, культуре и СМИ, где нам предстоит оживить имеющиеся давние прочные традиции, более активно **задействуя** современные технологии, включая дистанционное образование.

2) Это можно сделать, используя Внешэкономбанк, **задействовав** средства ФНБ. В этом году организаторы впервые отступили от традиции, **не задействовав** старинное строение в качестве естественной декорации.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Значение  "неправильного"  слова "задействуя" сходно с деепричастием "используя", **но очень близкими синонимами они  не являются.** Использовать - это пассивный вариант, а **задействовать – значит перевести ресурс в активную фазу.** И потребность в таком значении слова, очевидно, есть, если судить по следующим примерам (причем отнюдь не в бытовой или разговорной сфере): [http://context.reverso.net/перевод/русский-английский/,+задействуя](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/,+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8F)

Comment: Я одного не понимаю, вы тоже предлагаете считать словари устаревшими на основании более чем сомнительных примеров?

Comment: @IrinaGL Третьего дня вы с такой надеждой вопрошали о шансах на попадание в словарь другого неясного слова - неужели изменили подход ко всем словам сразу? :)

Comment: Я предлагаю спокойно, без эмоций разобраться в вопросе. Во-первых,  для образования глаголов СОВЕРШЕННОГО ВИДА могут использоваться (и активно используются) суффиксы "несовершенного вида".  А во-вторых, обратим внимание  на "сомнительные примеры". Там, как мне кажется, подразумевается именно несовершенный вид, например: "...нам предстоит оживить имеющиеся давние прочные традиции, более активно задействуя  (=используя) современные технологии".   Замена сделана, но семантика неточная.  Значит, надо отказаться от слова, если в словарях отсутствует форма несов. вида (или пока отсутствует)?

Comment: @Alex_ander пожалуйста, не переходите на личности. Вы умышленно неверно трактуете мою позицию. И это не делает Вам чести. *Я предлагаю спокойно, без эмоций разобраться в вопросе* - так разобрались уже. ***Употребление формы несовершенного вида не соответствует словарной норме.***

Comment: @Sibylla Я думаю, что суть проблемы в происхождении слова: принято ссылаться на практику военных как его источник. Военные не рассуждают о том, будут они задействовать что-то время от времени или нет, они ждут приказа "задействовать" ресурс (однократно). Поэтому потребности использовать такой глагол в несовершенном виде у них нет. При переносе в административную, техническую и позже - в бытовую сферу такая потребность в планировании "действий по задействованию" возникла, что и проявилось в практике употребления несов. вида.

Comment: Однако словари, зафиксировавшие когда-то это слово как "разговорное" со сниженным оттенком (что тоже изменилось), продолжали опираться на прежние примеры употребления в сов. виде и заимствовали статьи из прежних слов. изданий, трактуя такой подход как норму.

Comment: @Alex_ander *Однако словари,* - Назвать хоть один подобный словарь, Вы, однако, не смогли. Не люблю повторять, но придется. ***Употребление формы несовершенного вида не соответствует словарной норме***. Никакой. Ни разговорной, ни книжной.

Comment: @Sibylla, я прошу все-таки ответить. Вы предлагаете на основании ваших рассуждений разрешить использование варианта, ныне считающегося ненормативным? И даже советуете его использовать? Абитуриенту, например, на экзамене?

Comment: Если внимательно прочитать вопрос, то  речь идет об использовании   формы "задействуя" при обозначения текущего действия, а это возможно в том случае, если глагол "задействовать" может иметь значение несовершенного вида. В словарях такого значения нет, но по факту такая форма активно используется, так как существует объективная потребность в  слове с таким значением (а заменить его  нечем). Поэтому скорее всего несовершенный вид   в дальнейшем будет узаконен словарями. Это ответ на  вопрос, заданный участником нашего форума.

Comment: Что касается практического решения, то можно посоветовать корректорам  не считать "задействуя" ошибкой,  а абитуриенты  должны быть в курсе сложившейся .ситуации.

Comment: В "Учебном орфографическом словаре" В. В. Лопатина (2010, с. 226) есть соотв. глагол страдательного залога "задействоваться, -уется" (меток сов./несов. вида в словаре нет). Трудно себе представить, чтобы форма "**задействуется**" (кем-то) использовалась в значении будущего времени (что  соответствует сов. виду) - скажут "будет задействован" или "будет задействоваться" (аналогично модификациям двувидового глагола "использовать": использовать - используется - будет использован или использоваться).

Answer (score 2):

Такая форма невозможна потому, что нет глагола, её порождающего.
Есть пара *действовать-задействовать*. Первый глагол несовершенного вида, второй - совершенного. Для образования деепричастия несовершенного вида требуется и глагол несовершенного вида. Но от "задействовать" его невозможно образовать.

Подберите глагол с подходящим значением, например, *"использовать"*. От него будет деепричастие *используя*. Или *применять - применяя*.

Добавлю.
Глагол "задействовать" не относится к т.н. двухвидовым глагола. Употребление его в контексте, подразумаевающем несовершенный вид и образование от него деепричастия несовершенного вида, - грубое отступление от литературной нормы.

Смотрела по нескольким словарям. Вот хотя бы тут.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: Пару "действовать - задействовать" можно отнести лишь  к редко используемому значению "**начать действовать**" (У лукоморья задействовал свежепостроенный маяк.) _непереходного_ глагола "задействовать". В нашем же случае вопрос касается _переходного_ глагола с другим значением - "**привести в действие**", для которого пара имеет вид "_задействовать - задействовать_", то есть глагол _двухвидовый_ (примеры использования приводились).

Comment: Разные пары несовершенного/совершенного видов образуют и некоторые другие глаголы, употребляемые в разных значениях. Например, глагол "запросить" может употребляться со смыслами "_сделать запрос_" (запросить документы) или "_начать просить_" (запросить пощады, мира), соответствующие пары: "запрашивать - запросить" и "просить - запросить". Это объясняет и недоразумение с парой действовать - задействовать.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "задействовать" можно отнести к **двувидовым**: в зависимости от контекста он выступает как глагол совершенного или несовершенного вида.

> Когда отключилось электричество, главный энергетик больницы
>   **задействовал** дизель-генератор. (пр. время сов. вид)
>
> В разных экстренных случаях он **задействует** подходящие технические
>   средства. (наст время, несов. вид)

Этот глагол вполне сопоставим с глаголом "**завещать**", обычно включаемым в популярные списки двухвидовых глаголов. Соответственно, нет проблем в образовании деепричастия несовершенного вида, которое, как и в случае исходного глагола "завещать", отличается от варианта совершенного вида (*завещав - завещая, задействовав - задействуя*).

> **Задействовав** имевщийся резерв боевых слонов, Ганнибал решил исход
>   сражения.
>
> **Задействуя** всё новые и новые препараты, спортсмен на протяжении многих
>   лет уклонялся от поимки на применении допинга.

Таким образом, деепричастие "**задействуя**" может быть образовано.

Comment: А кто это относит "задействовать" к двухвидовым? Хоть один словарь это делает? Ну а то, что в интернете можно найти любую форму, даже самую фантастическую - не новость.

Comment: Определение: "Двувидовые глаголы — глаголы, лишённые формального выражения значений вида и _употребляющиеся в значениях как совершенного, так и несовершенного вида_." Это сильнее списков, коротких или длинных.

Comment: Не думаю, что сильнее списков. И уж точно не сильнее словаря. Глагол задействовать к двухвидовым не относится. Вы приводите примеры употребления, не соответствующего литературной норме. Или ошибочно трактуете как несовершенный вид.

Comment: _<Не думаю...>_ А зря. Языковая практика в отношении нашего слова уже давно расходится с **рекомендациями** словарей: _Теория расходится с практикой и еще в одном отношении, а именно: некоторые глаголы широко употребляются как **двувидовые** вопреки рекомендациям словарей. Скажем, глагол **задействовать** толковые словари русского языка рекомендуют считать формой СВ, в то время как он активно употребляется в современном дискурсе **в обоих видах** и случаи типа мы будем задействовать в текстовых корпусах, в том числе и в НКРЯ [нац. корпус], представлены достаточно широко._ (см. источник ниже)

Comment: Русский глагольный вид в его связях с переводом. (Вестник СПбГУ. Сер. 9. 2015. Вып. 3) http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/russkiy-glagolnyy-vid-v-ego-svyazyah-s-perevodom.pdf Пример другого научного текста, в котором слово с "задейств-" (включая производные от глагола причастия) встречается порядка 35 раз с чередованием сов/несов. видов: http://aletuchiy.narod.ru/dissertation/dissertation_lability.pdf  Это диссертация, написанная под р-вом д.ф.н., так что призываю вас избегать термина "фантастический".